# Suggestion for a change of a grid background of graph using an android plot library

Tags: android, androidplot

I want to make look like grid background as a full screen, [image: [look like this image].

...by using android plot library. Can anyone suggest a good implementation of that.

I'm going to change bitmapshader by creating bitmap, to pass
`RectF rect = plot.getGraph().getGridRect();
        BitmapShader myShader = new BitmapShader(
                Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(
                        BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                                getResources(),
                                R.drawable.graph_background),
                        1,
                        (int) rect.height(),
                        false),
                Shader.TileMode.REPEAT,
                Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
       Matrix m = new Matrix();
       m.setTranslate(rect.left, rect.top);
       myShader.setLocalMatrix(m);

plot.getGraph().getGridBackgroundPaint().setShader(myShader);`

this give error for  (int) rect.height(), null pointer exception for this

Comment: You shouldnt try to use a bitmap to represent the grid.  Instead you need to numerically define the characteristics of the grid and let Androidplot draw it for you.  Unfortunately it's impossible to tell from the image what the characteristics you care about are.  could you describe the goal a little more precisely along the lines of "each square should be 10x10 pixels" or "i want to display a 100x100 grid".

Comment: i want to make small square box as much possible and remove the built in grid line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a more precise description of what you're trying to do the best I can do is to provide a general answer to how you accomplish your goal.  Here's how you would display a grid of 25x25 px boxes:

```
plot.setDomainStep(StepMode.INCREMENT_BY_PIXELS, 25);
plot.setRangeStep(StepMode.INCREMENT_BY_PIXELS, 25);
plot.getGraph().getDomainGridLinePaint().setColor(Color.BLUE);
plot.getGraph().getRangeGridLinePaint().setColor(Color.BLUE);
```

You said in your comments that you wanted to make the boxes as small as possible, so if you really want to do that, you could specify a size of 1 by 1  instead.